# dynamic image attach to mouse over drop down

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to dynamically attach image to mousemove and then drop it to a div or . like post it notes.

Let me explain more. After completing text entry and click submit. the box will disappear and post-it image will attach to mouse and drop anywhere in a div.

```
    Function dataInputfn () {
    $('#dataInput').fadeIn();   
}

$('#submitTest').click(function(){
    $ ('#dataInput'). Fadeout ();
    $('<div id="NoteNew" class="dragNote"><img src="image.jpg" width="60px"/></div>').appendTo($('#div'));
    //Cursor:url(images/image0.jpg);
    noteDragFunc();
    });

Function noteDragFunc () {
    $( "#NoteNew" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid", stack: "#NoteNew"});
    $( "#chart" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var coord = ui. draggable. position ();
        alert (coord. top);
        btnDrop = true;
    }

    });
}
```

Instead of appending to dive I need to attach this image to mouse and drop anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling `draggable()` won't actually attach your element to the mouse's position.

Also, if you're listening to the `click` event, then the mouse button is already "UP" when you  trigger the `noteDragFunc` function.

What you're trying to do might work if you change the event to `.mousedown()` but I wouldn't count on it. The user would still need to actually click on the NewNote div.

You might need to use something other than draggable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Schmicko. lets say if I have a mousemove and image is moving with the mouse. What should I put mousedown() function, to place the image on some div. or anywhere.